# QT Quick3D: View3D shows Model in the editor but if i run the application i cant see my model

Tags: qt, qml, qt3d, qtquick3d

I'm using **Qt Quick 3D** and want to display a simple 3D model by using **View3D**. I imported my model and set it as the source for it. After that, I could see it in the editor, but if I run the application it doesn't show.

Here you can see that the green 3d model is shown in the editor:
[image]

But if I run my program, the model is missing:
[image]

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: you can see my code if you zoom in my first picture

Comment: It seems that you do not know the SO rules: All code provided by the OP must be as text. Read [ask] and review the [tour]